# Link in carousel plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hyperlink, carousel

Hi I have a carousel in my wordpress page but I can't seems to find a way of how to put a link on each of the images. I am using the Wordpress Carousel Free plugin and there are no support from the author.

The website is http://eyeandretina.com.au/ and the carousel is the one with the title Affiliated institutions.

Or you if have any free plugin that will allow me to insert a link on each of the images that would be great.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many other **free plugins** that can be useful to achieve your desired result.

1. [**Logo Slider**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/logo-slider/)
2. [**Easy Logo Slider**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-logo-slider/)
3. [**Best Logo Slider**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/best-logo-slider/)

I would suggest [**Logo Slider**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/logo-slider/).

Or even you can search more plugins [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=logo+slider).